# Editable checkbox only column in QTableView

Tags: c++, qwidget, qtableview, qt5.3, qcheckbox

I have column with a checkbox in a `QTableView`. The checkbox is generated by:

1. returning `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` in overridden `flags` member function
2. in overridden `data()` function I return a `Qt::CheckState` for `role == Qt::CheckStateRole` according to data

Works, see screenshot.

But beside the checkbox I have some editable textbox in the column. **How can I get rid of this textbox** (where I have entered "dsdsdsds" for demonstration? Clarification, **the checkbox shall be editable**, but nothing else.

[image: Readmode]
[image: Editmode]

---

As requested, I can only show simplified version

```
Qt::ItemFlags MyClass::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const {
 Qt::ItemFlags f = QAbstractListModel::flags(index);
 ... return f if index is not target column ....
 // for target column with checkbox
 return (f | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable; )
}


QVariant MyClass::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
  .. do something for other columns
  .. for checkbox column
  if (role != Qt::CheckStateRole) { return QVariant(); }
  bool b = ... get value for checkbox column
  Qt::CheckState cs = b ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked;
  return QVariant(static_cast<int>(cs));
}
```

If I remove `Qt::ItemIsEditable` then the checkbox is read only too. I later found an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15770018/356726) with a similar approach.

---

Remark: No duplicate of [A checkbox only column in QTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409457/a-checkbox-only-column-in-qtableview)

Comment: can you show us your current code? or give us a minimally complete example?

Comment: @HorstWalter, what about removing the `Qt::ItemIsEditable` flag?

Comment: Then the checkbox is readonly, which is not what I want. Updated the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the flag

`Qt::ItemIsEditable`

with the flag

`Qt::ItemIsEnabled`

The first one tells Qt to create an editor for the value present in the model, which seems to be a texteditor in your case.
If the value is of type `bool` then a dropdown list containing `true` and `false` would be shown instead.

Comment: setting Qt::ItemIsEnabled will just disable the column. removing Qt::ItemIsEditable will set the field to readonly