# Adding CheckBox with QSqlQueryModel shown in QTableview and other columns are empty

Tags: qt, checkbox, qtableview, qsqlquerymodel

I am using the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35319633/7837304) to add checkbox in tableview. I want to show it in the first column.

Here is my code:

mysqlquerymodel.h

```
#ifndef MYSQLQUERYMODEL_H
#define MYSQLQUERYMODEL_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QMap>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>

class MySqlQueryModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MySqlQueryModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex & index) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role);
private:
    QMap<int, Qt::CheckState> check_state_map;
};
#endif // MYSQLQUERYMODEL_H
```

mysqlquerymodel.cpp

```
#include "mysqlquerymodel.h"
Qt::ItemFlags MySqlQueryModel::flags(const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return 0;
    if (index.column() == 0)
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
    return  Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
}

QVariant MySqlQueryModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    if(role== Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        if(index.column() == 0)
        {
            if (check_state_map.contains(index.row()))
                return check_state_map[index.row()] == Qt::Checked ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked;
            return Qt::Unchecked;
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

bool MySqlQueryModel::setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role)
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return false;
    if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole && index.column() == 0)
    {
        check_state_map[index.row()] = (value == Qt::Checked ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
    }
    return true;
}
```

manage.cpp

```
void manage::on_selectBtn_clicked()
{
    QString query=QString("add_time,client_id,client_product_id,continent,country,region,city,ip,app_name,dev_os,dev_os_ver,dev_model,tusin_note,classify_note,detect_note,runtime_stats FROM ts_identify_record WHERE %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 ORDER BY add_time")
            .arg(timeRange()).arg(ipAddress()).arg(cellphone()).arg(product()).arg(country()).arg(province()).arg(city());
    qDebug()<<statment;
    QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::database();
    MySqlQueryModel *model=new MySqlQueryModel;
    model->setQuery(query,db);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
}
```

When I click the button, only the first column shows a checkbox and the other columns are empty. But the line count is correct and the checkbox can be clicked. It wouldn't be a problem when I just use *QSqlQueryModel*.

Another problem is that my `select` result should be 16 columns, but the first column is filled with checkbox. When I add `model->insertColumn(0);`, `tableview` shows 17 columns instead.

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the `MySqlQueryModel::data` method, you return the desired value only for the first column and only for the `Qt::CheckStateRole` role. For other cases, you return the `QVariant()`. To fix this, you have to return the necessary value for other cases. For example, you can return the value of the base class method:

```
QVariant MySqlQueryModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    if(role== Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        if(index.column() == 0)
        {
            if (check_state_map.contains(index.row()))
                return check_state_map[index.row()] == Qt::Checked ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked;
            return Qt::Unchecked;
        }
    }
    return QSqlQueryModel::data(index,role);//!!!!!
}
```

And, ofc, you have the constructor of MySqlQueryModel like this:

```
MySqlQueryModel::MySqlQueryModel(QObject *parent) : QSqlQueryModel(parent), check_state_map()
{
}
```

PS. Sorry for my English ;)

Comment: @FrozenM, providing the code snippet is much appreciated. However, have in mind that code only answers are usually considered as low quality and deleted. Please, explain how this code solves the problem.